# What it is this thing above the ceiling?

Tags: ceiling

It is in apartment on 10th floor.
I suppose it may be the ventilation tube, but I can't understand why the ventilation tube has such a thick walls. And why it ends there, instead of going to some grill in the ceiling...

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can get a closer shot of it?  Also...ewww at the NM in a high-rise apartment building!

Comment: So far there is no way to get a closer shot without opening the ceiling.:( I've made this shot after opening the outlet which looks like ventilation grill but has nothing connected to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a plenum return to me, especially since you said there's a ceiling grill into this area. Basically the false ceiling is acting as part of the ductwork. Very common in commercial buildings, less so in residential... but not at all unreasonable.

Comment: Does make the "not remotely plenum rated" NM wire look even worse, though. You won't die from the smoke off the network wire (if it's the usual blue=plenum wire) but the power wiring will do you in...ewww indeed.

Comment: What, you:re expecting the typical cable installer of landlords to have a Clue?   ;-J

Comment: No, I'm just sad to see the results of a throughly bribed building inspector endangering more lives where code has "solved" this particular means of killing people... If it was followed.

Comment: Is a plenum so dangerous for NM wires?

Comment: Not until there's a fire... at which point flammable and dripping plastic will make the problem worse ...

Comment: Happily there is a centralised smoke-alarm system, and the thick metal tube visible from left - is the fire sprinkles supply (there are a lot of hot-sensible sprinkles all over this apartment in ceiling). It is in New Zealand. I know nothing about the building codes here, perhaps it is OK in NZ... I've just bought this apartment, so trying to understand what is what... So far still can't get why the walls of this tube are so thick...

Comment: the toxic smoke from the burning plastic makes it worse faster. The insulation on plenum rated cables is not quite fireproof, but has a low level of toxic smoke production compared to "normal" plastic insulation. The thick walls on the tube are almost certainly (thermal) insulation, as has been mentioned in other answers/comments.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like somebody forgot to connect an HVAC supply duct -- probably to the vent you opened to take the picture!  The "thick walls" on the duct are probably insulation, which is why I suspect it is a supply duct.